# Defining variables efficiently according to a parameter that may take several values

Tags: python, function, variables, python-3.x

I have this function that defines and returns variables `a` and `b` depending on the value of the parameter `orientation`.

```
        def myfunc(orientation, l, w):


            if orientation == 1:
                a = -w
                b = l
            elif orientation == 2:
                a = -l
                b = w
            elif orientation == 3:
                a = -w
                b = -l
            elif orientation == 4:
                a = -l
                b = -w
            elif orientation == 5:
                a = w
                b = l
            elif orientation == 6:
                a = l
                b = w
            elif orientation == 7:
                a = w
                b = -l
            elif orientation == 8:
                a = l
                b = -w

            return a, b
```

My question is: is there a more compact and/or more efficient way to do the same thing? and if there is a better way, which is it?

Comment: Why are there  for loops? And where does l,w come from?

Comment: There were for loops because I took the code from a far more complex one. I removed them because they did not contribute to the question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way would be to use a dictionary . Example -

```
def myfunc(orientation, l, w):
    return { 1: (-w, l), 2: (-l, w), 3: (-w, -l),
             4: (-l, -w), 5: (w, l), 6: (l, w),
             7: (w, -l), 8: (l, -w) }[orientation]
```

Please note this evaluates all possible values in the dictionary and then selects the appropriate value to return based on the `orientation` as the key. You should not use this method if want the values to be evaluated only when needed.

Demo -

```
>>> def myfunc(orientation, l, w):
...     return {1: (-w, l), 2: (-l, w), 3: (-w, -l),
...             4: (-l, -w), 5: (w, l), 6: (l, w),
...             7: (w, -l), 8: (l, -w)}[orientation]
...
>>> myfunc(3,3,4)
(-4, -3)
```

---

The above would end up in a `KeyError` , if the key is not found. If its possible that you call this function with an orientation not found in the dictionary, you can use .`get(key, default)` , to make it return some default other default value. Example -

```
def myfunc(orientation, l, w):
    return { 1: (-w, l), 2: (-l, w), 3: (-w, -l),
             4: (-l, -w), 5: (w, l), 6: (l, w),
             7: (w, -l), 8: (l, -w) }.get(orientation) #This returns `None` if orientation is not found in the dictionary. Use `.get(orientation, defaultval)` for some other default value.
```

Answer (score 3):

First, the loops are unnecessary; only the values assigned in the very last iteration will be returned. Once you get rid of those, it's fairly easy to see the pattern:

```
def myfunc(orientation, l, w):

    a, b = (w, l) if orientation % 2 else (l, w)

    if orientation <= 4:
        a = -a
    if orientation in (3, 4, 7, 8):
        b = -b

    return a, b
```

Answer (score 1):

Not likely to be faster, but more succinct (and raises the same exceptions when `orientation` is "invalid"):

```
def myfunc(orientation, l, w):
    if 1 <= orientation <= 8:
        a = (-w, -l, -w, -l, w, l, w, l)[orientation - 1]
        b = (l, w, -l, -w)[(orientation - 1) % 4]

    return a, b
```

Comment: Please note, this would error out if orientation is not between 1 and 8 , but so would OP's code.

Comment: Yup. I was mirroring behavior intentionally; it raises the same `NameError` that the original code does (the omission is just a heck of a lot more obvious since there is only one place `a` and `b` are assigned, rather than 8).